# What is the best approach for setting startup variables in Matlab that are unaffected by commands such as `clear`?

Tags: matlab, environment-variables, startup

I have a situation in which a large amount of data output from Matlab programs needs to be stored in a specific location that can vary from machine to machine.  What I'd like to have is a global variable that is set at startup for each machine.  This variable could then be used by the various programs in order to determine the directory to store the output.  **Note** the approach will need to be *platform independent* as there a potentially 3 operating systems that will run these scripts.

**One** approach I considered is using `setenv`:

```
setenv('DATDIR',fullfile(path,to,dir));
```

Then the script/function could query this variable using:

```
savedir = getenv('DATDIR');
```

In this case the variable is unaffected by `clear` inside the Matlab environment.

**Another** approach I thought to use is simply creating a function (like `matlabroot`), which is on the path and simply returns a string to which the data directory path is assigned.

```
function path = datroot()
    path = fullfile(path,to,dir);
end
```

**Finally, to my question:** Is there another way to achieve the same result? If Matlab has it's own environment variables, I'd rather use those instead of functions or system-level variables.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [getpref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getpref.html)/[setpref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setpref.html)/[ispref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ispref.html)/[addpref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/addpref.html)/[rmpref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rmpref.html) set of functions. According to the documentation:

> Preference values are persistent and maintain their values between
>   MATLAB sessions. Where they are stored is system dependent.

This is like `.ini` or Java `.properties` files, but instead uses  MAT-files to persist the values (which can be of any MATLAB type). On my Windows machine, the file used is stored as:

```
%APPDATA%\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2010b\matlabprefs.mat
```

Comment: thanks for this answer.  `addpref` and `getpref` fit the bill precisely.